# SQL Server : how to count linked values in a column and count the number of link

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server and SSMS 15.0

Context: I have a driver's table (tb_driver) who makes a trip and goes through stations.

I have a section table (tb_section), these sections are identified by a departure and arrival station. There are stations in the trip that will never be part of a section (belair, chidda, etc.)

There are stations in the trip that make sections in the section table but without being a section in the trip.

How to count the number of sections in the trip?

tbdriver

| USERNAME | TRIPID | OUTTIME | STATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 06:26 | **ADELAIDE** |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 06:32 | BELAIR |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 06:36 | CHIDDA |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 06:40 | DRAPER |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 06:45 | **EDEN** |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 06:50 | GRANGE |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 06:54 | KILBURN |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 07:02 | LARGS |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 07:13 | **MARINO** |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 07:23 | **OSBORNE** |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 07:31 | PINERA |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 07:55 | **TAPERO** |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 08:00 | TONSLEY |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 08:06 | **UNLEY** |
| TGX7200 | 7802 | 03-05-21 08:17 | **WOMMA** |

tbsection

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| ADELAIDE | EDEN |
| MARINO | OSBORNE |
| PINERA | TAPERO |
| TAPERO | UNLEY |
| UNLEY | WOMMA |
| LARGS | EDEN |
| MARINO | VILLAS |
| WOMMA | TONGS |
| MARINO | LARGS |

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eJTfHqPfomLr5VpYVS8oKx/0)

The query below excludes all rows into tb_driver where stations is not present into column start and end from tb_section

```
select tb_driver.*
from tb_driver
where exists (select *
                  from tb_section
                  where tb_section.start = tb_driver.station or tb_section.end = tb_driver.station
                 );
```

| id | USENAME | TRIP_ID | OUT_TIME | STATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TGX7200 | 7802 | 2021-05-03 06:26:00 | ADELAIDE |
| 5 | TGX7200 | 7802 | 2021-05-03 06:45:00 | EDEN |
| 8 | TGX7200 | 7802 | 2021-05-03 07:02:00 | LARGS |
| 9 | TGX7200 | 7802 | 2021-05-03 07:13:00 | MARINO |
| 10 | TGX7200 | 7802 | 2021-05-03 07:23:00 | OSBORNE |
| 11 | TGX7200 | 7802 | 2021-05-03 07:31:00 | PINERA |
| 12 | TGX7200 | 7802 | 2021-05-03 07:55:00 | TAPERO |
| 14 | TGX7200 | 7802 | 2021-05-03 08:06:00 | UNLEY |
| 15 | TGX7200 | 7802 | 2021-05-03 06:17:00 | WOMMA |

Now I must calculate number of section (tb_driver)
The section goes from start to end (tb_section)

I have to count the number of section present in the driver table but these sections are defined in the tb_section table.
For example: I know from the section table that Adelaide-Eden is a section, but in the tb_drive I can only identify a section from a different row.

Expected results:

```
Adelaide - Eden = 1
Marino -   Osborne = 1
Pinera -   Tapero = 1
Tapero -   Unley = 1
Unley -   Womma = 1
Total 5   sections
```

Answer (score 0):

may be it can help...
[FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eJTfHqPfomLr5VpYVS8oKx/1)

first I concat in the table section start en end to create a new column : concat_section.
in the second table I create a new column section_driver_concat who concat STATION with the following row
then I keep all rows if start en end from tb_section are present into column station from table driver

```
with sc as
            (
              select *,
              CONCAT(start,'-',end) as concat_section
              from tb_section
              ),
    
    section_driver_concat as
        (
        select tb_driver.*, CONCAT(STATION,'-',LEAD(STATION,1) OVER (PARTITION BY USENAME ORDER BY OUT_TIME ASC)) as concat_section_driver
        from tb_driver
        where exists (select *
                          from tb_section
                          where tb_section.start = tb_driver.station or tb_section.end = tb_driver.station
                         )
        )
        select count(*)
        from section_driver_concat as sdc
        inner join sc ON sc.concat_section = sdc.concat_section_driver;
```